# Setting tkinter treeview header colour in W10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This works on W7, W10 WSL but not in W10.  I'm using python 3.7.3 on W7,  3.6.9 on WSL and 3.7.3 (anaconda) on W10.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview, Style

root = Tk()

style = Style()
style.configure('lview.Treeview.Heading', background='green', foreground='white')

list_tag = ['Common', 'Scientific', 'English']
list_plant = [
    ['binahong', 'anredera cordifolia', 'madeira vine' ],
    ['chien hom', 'persicaria odorata', 'vietnamese coriander' ],
    ['daun kaduk', 'piper sarmentosum', 'wild pepper'],
    ['pandan', 'pandanus amaryllifolius', 'screwpine']]


lview = Treeview(root, columns=list_tag[1:], style='lview.Treeview')
# Set up headings
col_index = -1
for tag in list_tag:
    col_index += 1
    lview.heading(f'#{col_index}', text=tag)

for num, plant in zip(range(len(list_plant)), list_plant):
    lview.insert(
        parent='',
        index='end',
        iid=num,
        text=plant[0],
        values=plant[1:])

lview.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

On W7, W10 WSL, the heading is green but on W10, the heading is white.  There is just a white bar since white on white does not show anything.  If I change the foreground to purple, the purple text shows up but the background is still white.

Is there some setting on W10 that will give the treeview heading some colour?  If not, I'll just have to change this to a standard grid.

**Edit**

I tried the following in wish, the windowed tclsh

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

ttk::style configure "lview.Treeview.Heading" -background "green" -foreground "purple"

ttk::treeview .tree -columns "aa bb" -displaycolumns "aa bb" -style "lview.Treeview"
.tree heading aa -text "Scientific" -anchor  center
.tree heading bb -text "English" -anchor  center
pack .tree
.tree insert {} end -text "binahong" -values [list  "anredera cordifolia" "madeira vine"]
.tree insert {} end -text "chien hom" -values [list "persicaria odorata" "vietnamese coriander"]
```

Same problem so it looks like it may be a wish problem on W10.  The same code works on W7 and W10 WSL.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem has already been reported in https://bugs.python.org/issue36468

The fix is to get tkinter 8.6.10.

Guess I'll have to wait until Anaconda picks up this version.